# Does using "and" three times in a sentence make it a run-on?

Tags: word-usage, run-on-sentence

I'm currently writing a cover letter and I've got a rather long sentence with three "and"s. I personally feel it has a good flow, but I've gotten mixed feedback on whether or not it is appropriate. The sentence in question is below along with the sentence afterwards to illustrate why I am hesitant to simply replace an "and" with a period (ruins the flow in my opinion).

> I recently graduated summa cum laude from Iowa State University with a Bachelor of Science in mathematics and minors in actuarial sciences and business & entrepreneurship and I am eager to apply my education to the consulting actuary industry. During my time at Iowa State I also had the opportunity to study at the University of New South Whales in Sydney, Australia and take classes from the Applied Finance and Actuarial Studies department.

Comment: This is essentially a request for writing advice (and hence off-topic). // A comma after _entrepreneurship_ makes the long first sentence less reader-unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

You could lose an **and** by inserting a comma instead of a period. Like so:

> After recently graduating summa cum laude from Iowa State University
> with a Bachelor of Science in mathematics, and minors in actuarial
> sciences and business & entrepreneurship, I am eager to apply my
> education to the consulting actuary industry.
>
> During my time at Iowa State, I also had the opportunity to take classes in Applied Finance and Actuarial Studies, and study at the University of New South Wales in Sydney, Australia.

Note I also rewrote a bit of it (such as correcting the spelling of Wales).

Comment: Is getting rid of the "and" with commas just a suggestion to ease my worries about overuse? Or do you feel it actually sounds better without that "and"? Also, does sandwiching the minors between commas make them...well...more minor? Even though they were minors for my degree I feel as though they are big selling points for myself when applying so I don't want to downplay them.

Comment: Yes to both. It _is_ a suggestion to ease your worries and I _do_ think it sounds better that way. Just reads more smoothly, IMO. As far as sandwiching the minor studies, I agree with you. If that's an issue, you could try this: **After intensive study in the fields of actuarial sciences and business & entrepreneurship at Iowa State University, and ultimately graduating summa cum laude with a Bachelor of Science in mathematics, I am eager to apply my education to the consulting actuary industry.** That might be a way of doing it.